# How to open Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment as admin in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have problem to run Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment as admin and run my exe file in the batch file. I manage to open the Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment as admin using this code in batch:

```
Start "" "C:\Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment"
```

It works perfectly. but after I edited the codes so that the Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment will run my exe file, it cannot run. Here is the code that I use to run my exe file after opening Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment as admin.

```
Start "" "C:\Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment" firsttime.exe
```

Nothing happens. it just opens the Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment and nothing happens after that.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Wouldn't it be `"C:\Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment\firsttime.exe"`?

Comment: Nope. it doesnt work. it just open the Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment but didnt run the firsttime.exe